# why does the sequence of n/7 always have the same six digits in the same order in the decimal part?

Tags: decimal-expansion

I realized the other day that in the decimal representation of $\frac{n}{7}$, where $n=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, the decimal part always has the same sequence of six digits but shifted to start at a different number. Why is that?

To demonstrate:

$\frac{1}{7} = 0.142857...$

$\frac{2}{7} = 0.285714...$ (shifted right 2)

$\frac{3}{7} = 0.428571...$ (shifted right 1)

$\frac{4}{7} = 0.571428...$ (shifted right 4)

$\frac{5}{7} = 0.714285...$ (shifted right 5)

$\frac{6}{7} = 0.857142...$ (shifted right 3)

Comment: See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_number

Comment: Try dividing $1$ to $6$ by $7$ on paper and you'll see what's happening.